# How can I access an operator property of a Sequelize object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

With `Sequelize`, I get that we can do:

```
    sequelizeOptions.where = {
      [Op.and]: andValues
    };
```

But what if I want to later add:

```
sequelizeOptions.where[[Op.or]] = orValues
```

But that doesn't seem to work. How can I do this?

Comment: What about `sequelizeOptions.where[Op.or] = orValues` did that work?

Comment: I get `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'symbol' can't be used to index type 'WhereOptions<JobPostingAttributes> | WhereOptions<JobSeekerAttributes>'.ts(7053)`

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? If you add OR to AND then you might get unpredictable results. Show SQL examples of AND and of AND with OR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not really sure whether this will solve your issue but I was facing a similar issue and I solved it as follows-

```
        where: {
          [op.and]: [
            {
              [op.or]: [
                db.sequelize.literal(`\`user\`.\`delete_status\` = 0 `),
                db.sequelize.literal(`\`user\`.\`delete_status\` IS NULL`)
              ]
            },
            db.sequelize.literal(`\`user->comapanyId\`.\`id\` = 38`)
          ]
        }
```

Hope it helps!